# java.lang.ClassCastException: class ... is in unnamed module of loader 'app' - spring-boot-dev-tools

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

We have a larger Spring boot application which causes the following exeception:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class jpa.XVersion cannot be cast to class jpa.XVersion (jpa.XVersion is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; jpa.XVersion is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @671ef14f)
    at y.package.abc(XService.java:70)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

while starting from within IDEA IntelliJ in relationship with JPA classes.

The application works fine while starting from plain command line.

After we have removed the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

The execution from within the IDE works fine without any issues.

We are using:

- Idea IntelliJ 2020.1.2
- Spring Boot Version 2.3.1,
- JDK 11.0.7 (Adopt Open JDK),
- Apache Maven 3.6.3

Does someone has already observed that kind of issue?
Does exist a different solution then removing the dependency?

Comment: I faced the same problem, after restart the IDE and cleaning maven it was automatically fixed

Comment: In IntelliJ idea can you please try `Invalidate Cache and restart` from file menu.

Comment: Do you use Java 9 modules? It can be related to this: e.g. if there is a valid Java 9 module IDE places their classes into a module path instead of a classpath. If you can reproduce it in a sample project please feel free to file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the reproducer.

Comment: @Andrey  No I don't use any modules (no module-info.java) in our project. That's the weird thing about that.

Comment: I have the same problem using Spring Quartz and Blaze Persistence. Restart class loader might fail with some libraries: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable

Answer (score 1):

Disable the spring dev tools restart

You can disable the restart feature using the `spring.devtools.restart.enabled` property set to `false`. In most cases you can set this in your *application.properties* (this will still initialize the restart classloader but it won’t watch for file changes).

If you need to completely disable restart support, for example, because it doesn’t work with a specific library, you need to set a *System property* before calling `SpringApplication.run(…​)`.

For example:

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("spring.devtools.restart.enabled", "false");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

Reference [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-disable)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the dependency below and it worked.

org.springframework.boot
     spring-boot-devtools
     runtime
     true

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after invalidating the cache and restart, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MyBatis like me, you may need to check if the resultMap or resultType in xxx-mapper.xml is compatible with your target type.

This solution works for me. :-)